# How to pass v-for index to child in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the below parent and child components. In the parent I am using `obj.Array` with `v-for` to list multiple children components. The issue is that `stuff1` and `stuff2` will be the same for each child but I need to grab each element of `obj.array` for each child. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks

Parent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child v-bind:obj="obj" v-for="(arrVal, index) in obj.array" :id="index" :key="arrVal"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      obj: { stuff1: "str1", stuff2: "str2", array: ["arrVal1", "arrVal2", "arrVal3"] }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{obj.stuff1}}</p>
    <p>------</p>
    <p>{{obj.stuff2}}</p>
    <p>------</p>
    <p>{{obj.array[index]}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
export default {
  props: { obj: Object }
};
</script>
```

What I would like to render:

> str1
>   ------ str2
>   ------ arrVal1
>
> str1
>   ------ str2
>   ------ arrVal2
>
> str1
>   ------ str2
>   ------ arrVal2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="val in obj.array">
    <p>{{obj.stuff1}}</p>
    <p>------</p>
    <p>{{obj.stuff2}}</p>
    <p>------</p>
    <p>{{val}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
export default {
  props: { obj: Object }
};
</script>
```

What I am suggesting is just to iterate over the array in the child component.

Comment: How do you pass obj from the parent to this child???

Comment: @Daemach here is where you pass it: `v-bind:obj="obj"`